# probability of rolling at least N of C when rolling X dice

Tags: probability

I have been looking this up but am struggling to find a straightforward answer.
I am still confused about the process.

So basically what is the probability of rolling at least three of a particular number say X when rolling five dice.

I believe the way to go is work out the probability of rolling 5 of the same number then add it too the probability of 4 of the same number and so on.

so 1/6^5 + 1/6^4 + 1/6^3 + 1/6^2.

Is this correct or am I leaving something out?

I originally phrased my question wrong asking the probability of getting x of the same number.

A good example of what I mean is

The probability of rolling at least three 2's when rolling five dice

Comment: Why do you have $\frac16 ^2$ there if you only care about "at least 3 of the same number"? Also, are you saying that $P(\text{all 5 are the same number})=\frac16^5$? And $P(\text{exactly 4 are the same number})=\frac16^4$? This is not true.

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes the power of two was my mistake. and yes too the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First choose one to be shown $3$ times. There are $6\choose{1}$ ways to choose this die. Then use the standard binomial to get the probability of that selected die showing up exactly $3$ times.

$${6\choose{1}}\cdot{5\choose{3}}\cdot\frac{1}{6}^3\cdot\frac{5}{6}^2 \approx .193$$

And for the same number being shown exactly $4$ times:

$${6\choose{1}}\cdot{5\choose{4}}\cdot\frac{1}{6}^4\cdot\frac{5}{6}^1 \approx .0193$$

And for the same number being shown exactly $5$ times:

$${6\choose{1}}\cdot{5\choose{5}}\cdot\frac{1}{6}^5\cdot\frac{5}{6}^0 \approx 7.713\cdot10^{-4}$$

Then summing these $3$ results we get $p \approx 0.213$

**For a fixed value:**

We take away the $6\choose{1}$'s since we are no longer choosing $1$ of the $6$ die to be shown at least $3$ times. We have

$${5\choose{3}}\cdot\frac{1}{6}^3\cdot\frac{5}{6}^2 + {5\choose{4}}\cdot\frac{1}{6}^4\cdot\frac{5}{6}^1 + {5\choose{5}}\cdot\frac{1}{6}^5\cdot\frac{5}{6}^0 \approx 0.03549$$

Comment: Sorry for the first part are you just multiplying 1/6^3 * 5/6^2?

Comment: We cannot just make that calculation. That would be the probability of getting 3 of a particular side followed by 2 of other values. But we are interested in $3$ of one value and $2$ of another in $any$ order. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) may be of help.

Comment: Sorry I actually phrased my question wrong. I meant the probability of getting X amount of a particular number. for example The probability of rolling at least three 2's when rolling five dice

Comment: Oh I see. Then take away the $6\choose{1}$'s. I will edit my answer.

Comment: The one part I am not getting is the (5,3) . 1/6^3. Do I multiply it by 5 then 3 and add them? sorry I am pretty bad add the notation.

Comment: You multiply it by $5\choose{3}$ and do the addition separately. So $$\left({5\choose{3}}\cdot\frac{1}{6}^3\cdot\frac{5}{6}^2\right) + \left({5\choose{4}}\cdot\frac{1}{6}^4\cdot\frac{5}{6}^1\right) + \left({5\choose{5}}\cdot\frac{1}{6}^5\cdot\frac{5}{6}^0\right)$$

Comment: Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I don't Understand how too multiply (5,3) by the fraction. do you multiply it by five and 3? I'm sorry for all the questions and thank you so much for helping me with this.

Comment: ${5\choose{3}} = 10$ so just take $10\times{\frac{1}{6}^3}\times{\frac{5}{6}^2}$

Comment: ok this is the last question I promise, how does it = 10 ?

Comment: In general ${n\choose{k}} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k!)}$ so we have ${5\choose{3}} = {\frac{5!}{3!2!}}=10$

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) would be a useful read.

Comment: $5\choose 3$ is notation which means "from a group of 5 items, in how many ways can you pick 3 things". The formula for it is $\frac{5!}{3! 2!}=\frac{120}{6\times 2}=10$. (You know what a factorial is, yes?)

Comment: Yes Ok that makes allot of sense, thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this. It makes sense to me now,

Answer (score 2):

We assign a probability distribution to what we want to count. First define the random variable $X_1$ to be the number of $1$'s we throw, $X_2$ to be the number of $2$'s we throw, etc. Then $X_i$ is binomially distributed $B(\frac16,5)$. To compute the probability of throwing exactly $n$ of a particular number, say $N$, we have to find $$P(X_N=n)=P(X_1=n)$$ since $X_1$ has the same distribution as all the other $X_i$'s. Then $$P(X_1=n)={5\choose n}\frac1{6^n}\frac{5^{5-n}}{6^{5-n}}$$as described by the other answer. Then to find the probability of rolling at least $3$ of this number, you work out $$P(X_1=5)+P(X_1=4)+P(X_1=3)$$

Comment: Do you know what I Phrased my question wrong, I will edit it now.

Comment: Please add it to the end instead of changing it so our answers still apply to that portion.